# Typeorm: Is it possible to delete all migrations and recreate just one with my current entities?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem with TypeORM migrations telling me that some fields don't exist or there are duplicate keys when I try to run them in a new deployment.

Is it possible to delete all migrations and recreate just one with my current entities?

Stack:

- TypeORM
- NestJS
- MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to delete all migrations and recreate one.

- Remove all migration files from your `src/migrations` folder.
- Don't forget to delete data from migration table in your database. In typeorm, typically the migration table is called as `typeorm_migrations`.
- Regenerate the migration file for your current entities. Use typeorm command `npx typeorm migration:generate -n NameOfYourMigration`.
- After generating migration file, apply the changes to your database with `npx typeorm migration:run`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had trouble with the name of the migration, hence the problem to create a new migration from scratch!